# Reading attribute properties from inside a source generator

Tags: c#, roslyn, sourcegenerators

**BACKGROUND**

I'm trying my hand at C# source generators. This is primarily an experimental project, but the goal is to create a library that will assist the user in writing logs using a key-value pair format. There is meant to be a pre-defined set of common keys at compile time. The library won't know what these are until the user declares an `enum` and decorates it with a special attribute. The `enum` members can optionally be decorated with an additional attribute that declares what `Type` the key is (if the attribute is absent, we assume it is a string).  Here are the `enum`s I am using:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Enum)]
public class LogKeysAttribute : Attribute { }

[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class LogMemberAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type FieldType { get; set; }
}
```

So, as an example, we might have something like this:

```
[LogKeys]
public enum CommonKeys
{
    [LogMember(FieldType = typeof(int))]    FirstAsInt     = 1,
    [LogMember(FieldType = typeof(string))] SecondAsString = 2,
    ThirdAsImpliedString = 5,
}
```

Now what the library is going to do is create a new method like this:

```
public void Log(int? firstAsInt=null, string secondAsString=null, string thirdAsImpliedString = null)
{
    ...
}
```

**PROBLEM**

So far, I've gotten just about everything working the way I want, but I'm hung up on the part where I read the value of `FieldType` in the `LogMemberAttribute`.  I can see if the `LogMember` is there, and in the debugger, I can see that it was set to an `int` or `string`, but in the code I can't figure out how to pull that out and make use of it.

**SOURCE CODE**
Here is (a simplified version of) my `Execute` method (NOTE: I realize there are things that are sub-optimal here. That's OK--right now we are only worried about reading from attributes):

```
public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
{
    var compilation      = context.Compilation;

    //Declare our attributes that will be used
    //I had hoped adding it here would make the type available to use below, but no such luck
    var attributeDefinitionsSrc = @"
using System;
namespace LogWrapper
{
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Enum)]
  public class LogKeysAttribute : Attribute { }

  [System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Field)]
  public class LogMemberAttribute : Attribute
  {
    public Type FieldType { get; set; }
  }
}";

    //Add the attributes to the compilation
    context.AddSource("CustomAttributes.cs", attributeDefinitionsSrc);
    var attribSyntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(attributeDefinitionsSrc, (CSharpParseOptions)context.ParseOptions);
    compilation = compilation.AddSyntaxTrees(attribSyntaxTree);

    //Now we can get those symbols to use later
    var keyAttribute  = compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("LogWrapper.LogKeyAttribute");
    var memberTypeAttr = compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("LogWrapper.LogMemberAttribute");

    //targets will be anything that is an Enum declaration
    var targets = compilation.SyntaxTrees
                                 .SelectMany(x => x.GetRoot()
                                                   .DescendantNodesAndSelf()
                                                   .OfType<EnumDeclarationSyntax>());
    foreach (var t in targets)
    {
//bonus points if you can explain to me what the "SemanticModel" is and how it differs from a syntax tree.
//I see you can view the syntax tree at sharplab.io. Is there a place/way to view the semantic model?
        var targetType = ModelExtensions
                           .GetDeclaredSymbol(compilation.GetSemanticModel(t.SyntaxTree), t);

        //We are only interested in the first enum that has our KeyAttribute associated
        if (targetType != null &&
            targetType.GetAttributes().Any(x => x.AttributeClass.Equals(keyAttribute)) &&
            targetType is ITypeSymbol its)
        {
            //Here we get all the enum members (FirstAsInt, SecondAsString, etc.)
            //They are sorted by their enum value (FirstAsInt is 1, so it goes first)
            var iSymbolList = its.GetMembers()
                              .Where(x=>x is IFieldSymbol ifs && ifs.HasConstantValue)
                              .OrderBy(x => ((IFieldSymbol)x).ConstantValue)
                              .ToList();

            //Next we iterate over all the members
            foreach (var sym in iSymbolList)
            {
                //If this member has a LogMember attribute associated with it,
                // then we get that attribute.
                var attrib = sym.GetAttributes()
                          .FirstOrDefault(x=>x.AttributeClass?.Equals(memberTypeAttr) == true);
                if (attrib != default)
                {
                    //There was a LogMember attribute. This means I want to read the
                    // value of FieldType so I know what Type it should be.

                    // **** THIS IS THE PART THAT I CAN'T DO *****

   //Debugger shows list of 1 with value "{[FieldType, {Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.TypedConstant}]}"
                    var namedArgsList = attrib.NamedArguments;

   //Debugger shows an empty list
                    var constArgsList = attrib.ConstructorArguments;

   //Debugger shows "{[FieldType, {Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.TypedConstant}]}"
                    var firstArg      = namedArgsList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "FieldType");

   //Debugger shows value "{int}" and it shows the type as:
   //"object { Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Symbols.PublicModel.NonErrorNamedTypeSymbol}"
   //It seems the data I want is here, but I can't get to it...
                    var valAsObj      = firstArg.Value.Value;

   //Debugger shows null. We can't cast to a Type.
                    var asType        = valAsObj as Type;
                    }
                    //else assume string (code removed)
                }

                //by this point we have all the data we need to generate the code
                break;
            }
        }
```

So is it possible to fetch this data?  I'm afraid I'm not very good with SyntaxTrees and whatnot, so it seems likely there's something I could be doing that would give me what I want, but I just don't know what that is.

Comment: If you read into the Roslyn Github source, you'll see that `NonErrorNamedTypeSymbol` does not at any point inherit from `System.Type`, so you cannot make that cast. Can you use `Type.GetType(string)` to resolve the Type from the `NonErrorNamedTypeSymbol.Name` property?

Comment: I did try messing around with this a bit, but one of the issues I had here was that for the first one, it shows "int" and `Type.GetType("int")` does not work (has to be `GetType("System.Int32")`. Similarly, string has to be `GetType("System.String")`.  I suppose I COULD do a switch statement or something that says "if you get "int", return the type int, if you get string, return a string...", but I would really rather avoid this if possible. @AndrewH

Comment: Are there any limitations on what types `LogMemberAttribute` can define? Are they all primitive types?

Comment: Ideally, it could be any type.  In practice, your suggested hack would probably work at least 9 times in 10.

Answer (score 4):

Many questions here, but:

> //Debugger shows null. We can't cast to a Type.

The value in this case should be castable to INamedTypeSymbol, which is Roslyn's concept of a type. If you want to ask "is it an int" there's also a .SpecialType property on ITypeSymbol which gives you an enum for *some* common cases.

> bonus points if you can explain to me what the "SemanticModel" is and how it differs from a syntax tree.

A syntax tree is just syntax, that's it. Give us some text, we know what the tree is. The semantic model lets you ask questions about trees in a compilation, where the context is all of the trees plus references together.

> var targets = compilation.SyntaxTrees

You'll want to look at [ISyntaxReciever](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.isyntaxreceiver?view=roslyn-dotnet-3.11.0) for a way to walk trees that'll be a bit friendlier to our performance since we're better scheduling when stuff happens.

Comment: Well, it's not exactly what I was going for, but it's the best solution so far and will work in most cases.  What I did was to change `var asType` to be `valAsObj as INamedTypeSymbol`. Now I can set `Type symbolType = Type.GetType($"{asType.ContainingNamespace.Name}.{asType.Name}");`  This seems to do fine for most types, but it does cause a problem when trying to do something like `long?`  In that case, the name is "Nullable" and I can't get to the `long` part (although it does show up if I do `asType.ToString()`)